# Keep the bevel modifier from creating ngons and tris

Tags: modeling, modifiers, topology

How can I keep the bevel modifier from creating ngons and tris? I thought a quad-only mesh would do it, but it doesn't like topological gems, and the edge flow is too important.
Or is it Simply Imposible ?

Comment: For quad-only mesh, it is possible that bevel can generate quads (as shown in my answer), but I don't understand how it could generate Ngons. Could you show an image or file here?

Comment: if you bevel on edge of a cube youll get an ngon and i was askingif there issome method that automaticly trinagulates / make quads of of the ngon again

Comment: Anyway, see my updated answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any automatic way accompanied with Bevel modifier to operate like that. Some other manual solutions:

1. If you just want to triangulate, there is a **Triangulate** modifier for you to use;
2. You can also select all faces then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to convert them into Triangles;
3. If you want to keep quads as many as possible, select all ngon faces only, by **Select** >  **Select Face by Sides**, set it greater than 4 (As shown below), then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to convert all selected faces into triangles, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to convert them into quads by tweaking *Max Angle* in **F6** panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Bevel modifier uses Tris and ngons to create the bevel itself, in order to reduce any unnecessary vertices that you apply the modifier to any complex object; you should select your object, tab into edit mode, go under the tool bar and hit remove doubles. This will significantly reduce the amount of unnecessary vertices.

Comment: welli dont want ngons at all